# Imports causing verifyError? java

Tags: java, import, verifyerror

I'm working on a project where we want to re-use the code of a similar recent project. This time, however, we want to split the code into three libraries so it gets easier to work with on future projects where we we'll be re-using this code as well.

I'm going to describe the project set-up just like I have it in Netbeans.

Before, I had a Java Web Application project consisting of many source code packages and a bunch of libraries.

Now, we have distributed the source code packages into three Java Application projects. We need a fouth Java Web Application project where we import these three projects as libraries and we can test the RESTful web services implemented in the code.

The problem is that to make all imports work after refactoring, we ended up including all the libraries from the original project in all of the four new projects. We are pretty sure this is causing a `java.lang.VerifyError` that we have not been able to solve for a couple of days.

After refactoring the main project in 3 parts, they include each other as follows (they also include every library used in the original project):

```
A (A imports B and C)
|
B (B imports C)
|
C
```

The web application project imports everything: the three source code projects plus all the libraries used in the main project. If we don't include them, when we try to test the RESTful web services we can't see the resources on the left.

The question is if there is any suggestion on how we can organize our libraries so we stop getting this VerifyError (if this is the reason it is happening)

```
ERROR MESSAGE: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/couchbase/client/CouchbaseClient, method: asyncQueryAndReduce signature: (Lcom/couchbase/client/protocol/views/View;Lcom/couchbase/client/protocol/views/Query;)Lcom/couchbase/client/internal/HttpFuture;) Incompatible argument to function
```

I got that error message when testing a simple class that created a couchbase client. When we test the real web services, we get the same error with a bigger and more complex stack trace, but same error basically.

```
FULL ERROR WHEN WE RUN THE WEB SERVICE:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/couchbase/client/CouchbaseClient, method: asyncGetView signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/couchbase/client/internal/HttpFuture;) Incompatible argument to function
at models.cache.utils.PoolableCouchbaseClientObjectFactory.makeObject(PoolableCouchbaseClientObjectFactory.java:53)
at models.cache.utils.PoolableCouchbaseClientObjectFactory.makeObject(PoolableCouchbaseClientObjectFactory.java:24)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
at models.cache.utils.CouchbaseConnector.connectCache(CouchbaseConnector.java:48)
at models.cache.controllers.SessionCacheHandler.setUserSession(SessionCacheHandler.java:65)
at services.handlers.LoginPOSTHandler.run(LoginPOSTHandler.java:296)
at services.LoginResource.post(LoginResource.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:168)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message of the `VerifyError`?

Comment: Post the exact error message and stack trace, and the code causing it. I think you're just making incorrect assumptions. VerifyError doesn't have anything to do with imports.

Comment: I posted it. Any ideas? I assumed it was becouse of the imports becouse what's failing is a couchbase method that didn't fail before the refactor

Comment: It seem you run a different CouchDB version that the one you compiled against

Comment: Maybe the *problem* is at line 53 in PoolableCouchbaseClientObjectFactory. Paste that line too. Note that, if I remember correctly, Netbeans has that dangerous feature that can package uncompilable code

Comment: CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(this.serverList, this.bucketName, this.bucketPassword);

Answer (score 0):

Java is a compiled language, so there are two moments:

1. The compilation step, when the compiler is told to use your import statements, to build the qualified names to resolve your symbols. Once the bytecode has been generated, it doesn't contain any import statement, because imports are a source-code thing, they never exist at runtime. In the bytecode, every symbol is fully qualified with the package name.
2. The runtime verification, when the JVM verfiers takes care of matching a method invocation with that method's definition. This is when the `VerifyError` is thrown

This implies there are two different agents interested in loading definitions: the compiler and the JVM. Both can load classes definitions from the CLASSPATH, but at runtime, for example, your webapp classloader may also load classes from the WEB-INF/lib directory.

When developing libraries, you can add archives to your build path (or you can use a dependency management tool like Apache Ivy or Maven), but you should not pack dependencies in the output of the build process. It's up to the user to provide the required libraries.

So, for example you develop A and add the B and C project to the build path, so the compiler can resolve symbols and happily compile everything, but the final JAR must contains only classes for the project A. The same for B, and obviously for C.

When you develop your webapplication, you'll have A, B, C in your build path, but you should also take care of setting up a build process which copies everything in the WEB-INF/lib before deploying, otherwise you'll experience missing libraries at runtime.

As I said previously, you can organize your project with Maven, or you can manage dependencies with Ivy, or you can simply use proprietary Netbeans project, if Netbeans is a standard in your team and you don't want to adopt other technologies. If you choose the Netbeans way, you should add Netbeans projects as dependencies (NB, Netbeans **projects** , not just JAR files), so that when a library is updated, your webapp deployment script automatically grabs the modification and you don't have conflicting libraries installed in different places.

Comment: My three new projects all need more or less the same libraries. Is there any way to include them only in project C and then B and A get them when they import C?

Comment: Please, don't use the term *import*, it's misleading, since it's a valid Java instruction to make the compiler resolve symbols. If you mean *package* the required JARs in C so they are automatically available to all projects requiring C, then yes, there is, but it's bad practice and could break things. You'd better use a dependency framework which has the notion of *transitive* dependencies and manages everything for you. Maven and Ivy can do it for sure, I don't know if Netbeans manages transitive deps, but you really should look for Maven, because it's a de-facto Java standard